# EntityFramework Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I started out my own personal project to learn more about EntityFramework and MVC in a whole. I chose the Database First approach because that's the way I learned it on my job. The database looks like this:

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZV5Z.png)

This generates the following model:

[EntityFramework Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFfkP.png)

But the navigation properties are not the way I want it. First I named the foreign keys Country, League without Id as suffix. But that gave me navigation properties named like Country1 and League1 and that's something I see as bad naming, so I changed it around. But I still got one problem left, the navigation property for the CurrentChampion is called Club, wich is not a clear name.

How do I get EntityFramework to use the columnname for the navigation property instead of the name of the referenced table. Is there a way to do this without changing the model? Because if I have to change it in the Model designer I have to do that everytime I delete the table from the model and re-add it.

Comment: Just give different ID names to different tables, such as: LeagueId, ClubId, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The default name for navigation properties is the table name, no way to change this naming convention i'm aware of.  If you right click on the entity and add association you can name both ends what you want.